# What to do when I need to use `any` in typescript generics?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I wrote a wrapper to all my service responses, that looks like this:

```js
export type Response<T> {
  status: 'success' : 'failed';
  data?: T;
  error?: Error;
}
```

all my services return that, with either `success` and a value for `data` or with `failed` and a value for `error`

I tried to write an utility function that would build a `Response` for me in case of error, and it looks like this:

```js
private handleError(error: Error): Response<any> {
  if (error && isSomeSpecificError(error.message)) {
    return { status: 'failed', error: SpecificError(error) };
  }
  return { status: 'failed', error };
}
```

And it works fine, but ESLint complains about the `any` with the following message:

> ESLint: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)

If I use `unknown` then it fails for any function that returns the result of calling this function, given that it has a different `T`

Is there any way around this? Or is this one of the cases where I should ignore eslint *or* find another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how I would do it:

```
interface Success<T> {
    status: 'success';
    data: T
}

interface Failure {
    status: 'failed'
    error: Error;
}

export type Response<T> = Success<T> | Failure;

class Something {
    handleError(error: Error): Failure {
        if (error && error.message) {
            return { status: 'failed', error: new Error };
        }

        return { status: 'failed', error };
    }
}
```

In general, you don't want to use optional fields where a union can be used. This makes invalid states unrepresentable (for example, `{ status: 'success', error: new Error }` should never happen yet the approach that uses optional fields allows it).

When built from ground up, unions are more useful. Here, we were able to use the definition of `Failure` to say exactly what will be returned.

Comment: In this case it may not even need the `status` field.